# mongodb sort by dynamic property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am building application using node and mongoose. I have this model

```
{
    price: Number,
    price_special: Number,
    price_special_from: DateTime,
    price_special_to: DateTime
}
```

I am curious if I can sort collection by current price using aggregation framework. current price should be counted like this

```
function(model){
    if(now > model.price_special_from && now < model.price_special_to) {
        return model.price_special;
    } else {
        return model.price;
    }
}
```

I need to run this sort on big collections so i can not do it in application. only approach i have in mind is to make counted property updated by cron. which is not optimal.
Plase advise how to build `$project` query for this case.

---

**update**

I resolved this "duplicate" issue by using aggregation framework. I used `$cond` operator in combination with `$and` operator.

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project:
            {
                price: 1,
                price_special: 1,
                price_special_from: 1,
                price_special_to: 1,
                current_price:
                {
                    $cond: { if: {
                        $and: [
                            {$ne: ["$price_special", null]},
                            {$ne: ["$price_special_to", null]},
                            {$ne: ["$price_special_from", null]},
                            {$gt: [new Date(),"$price_special_from"]},
                            {$lt: [new Date(),"$price_special_to"]}
                        ]
                    },
                        then: "$price_special",
                        else: "$price"
                    }
                }
            }

        },{ $limit : 100 }
    ]
)
```

Comment: this is not exact duplicate. heading is similar but these are two different cases.